# Learning Swiss German handwriting alphabet

Tags: learning

I were unable to find paper with alphabet letters on it to start learning reading/writing in Swiss German. Searched native bookstores and still couldn't find those "1th grade school kids letters typing books". Does anybody know, where could I find such paper, so I could print it and start learning?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Your question makes me wonder what handwriting you learnt before and why you assume it to be any different from (Swiss) German handwriting (assuming a Latin script). Also, I wouldn’t know if there are any differences between Swiss and German German handwritings aside from personal preferences. As such, I’m voting to close this question as unclear. Don’t let that discourage you, you can edit your post to make the question clearer (that is explicitly encouraged here!). For any further questions, take the [tour] or visit the [help].

Comment: https://unterricht.educa.ch/de/uebungsreihe-schweizer-schulschrift

Comment: @Jan: Die Schweiz hat kein scharfes S.

Comment: @userunknown Das ist mir bewusst, aber ich meinte eigentlich die Formen der anderen 29 Buchstaben ;)

Comment: @Stephie, ich habe das auch nur gegoogelt.

Comment: @Jan, auch die Formen der Druckbuchstaben unterscheiden sich regional - typisches Beispiel z.B. ob 'f' auf der Grundlinie steht oder eine Unterlänge hat. Und wenn OP z.B. aus dem angelsächsischen Raum stammt, sind die Unterschiede noch deutlicher. Schulen geben typischerweise eine Schrift vor, daher ist die Frage IMHO nicht "unclear".

Comment: @Stephie, well, Luis writes that he wants to start learning, but he does not seem to a first grader, so it is a bit confusing. I also do not try to learn the *Schulausgangsschrift* currently used in Germany only because it differs from what was taught in the seventies (I assume).

Comment: @CarstenS , if Luis is were from the US (random example), his 'r', 'I' would look significantly different and so would some numbers. Besides, note that there are so many *completely different* fonts - who would blame someone from Japan or Korea or whatever for not knowing any Latin script?

Comment: @CarstenS Why there is no special characters like ß, ä, ë?

Comment: @Stephie Ja, ja, korrekt, möchte ich alles nicht bestreiten. Deswegen frage ich Luis ja auch *welche* Handschrift Luis bereits gelernt hat/nicht gelernt hat (vielleicht kommt Luis ja aus einer Gegend, in der kyrillisch oder arabisch geschrieben wird), und *warum* es *ausgerechnet die Schweizer* Handschrift sein soll. Deswegen und nur deswegen stimme ich derzeit fürs Schließen wegen Unklarheit. Mit diesen Informationen gegeben bin ich der erste, der für Wiederöffnen stimmen wird.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After 67 years of teaching a form of *cursive* ("Schnüerlischrift"), Swiss authorities have recommended substituting it with block letters for all schools in German-speaking Switzerland. As all fonts have slight differences, choosing one common set of letters is important for the benefit of learners. The suggested style is the **Luzerner Basisschrift**. It's use is recommended, but not mandatory.

The specific charm of the Luzerner Basisschrift is that it comes in [varieties](http://d-edk.ch/sites/default/files/basisschrift_uebersicht-eltern.pdf), starting as pure block letters, later suggesting "connecting" letters - vaguely resembling cursive - for easier flow and faster writing. The ultimate goal is to develop an individual style of hand that still remains well-legible for others.

You will easily find examples with the help of your favourite search engine or (in German) on the official website of the [D-EDK](http://d-edk.ch/medienmitteilungen/basisschrift-wird-die-neue-schulschrift).

---

Note that other Kantone might demand a different style, you might consider checking with the local authorities to be really sure, especially as the current recommendation is only a few months old.

---

Different from for example Germany and the US (and many other countries) Swiss primary schoolers start(ed) writing with *cursive*, namely the "Schweizer Schulschrift" or "Schnüerlischrift" which Carsten S [linked to](https://unterricht.educa.ch/de/uebungsreihe-schweizer-schulschrift) in his comment.

Comment: Thank you for explanation.  
CarstenS provided file isn't clear for me as it doesn't write letters in Roman Type(like: VvSs) and doesn't include all letters, it's very confusing for me.  

D-EDK includes good examples, but it's very different from CarstenS provided one.

When I were learning second language Russian I started with this - www.i.imgur.com/DcSYBra.jpg. That was the most clearest method for me! I tried googling, eventually tried in German (with google translator), but had no luck to find. Is it possible to find something similar?

Comment: @Luis All letters, including an instruction on strokes [here](https://volksschulbildung.lu.ch/-/media/Volksschulbildung/Dokumente/unterricht_organisation/faecher_wost_lehrmittel/faecher/Basisschrift/buchst_vorlagen_hausetiketten.pdf?la=de-CH). Note that the "house" is a common metaphor to explain where the letters go in the line. Just get yourself a notebook with these lines (or write on ordinary paper) and practise. Note that my first link gives these, too.

Comment: @Luis, I do not claim that the one that I linked to is very useful, I just found it by googling a bit (of course it helped that I can read German). It contains the 26 letters of the alphabet in alphabetical order ;) For the umlaut letters just add two little strokes above the letter. There is no *ß* in Swiss German, but you can adapt one from a German *Schulausgangsschrift*.